# Where is the uid after FirebaseAuth Package upgrade?

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

In previous version of firebase_auth: ^0.5.4, there was a option
***user.uid*** **(uid is of String type)**.

In the latest version of   firebase_auth: ^0.15.0+1, which option should I select to get ***user.uid*** or its replacement.

**Note about the breaking change in FirebaseAuth 0.12.0.**

1. Added new AuthResult and AdditionalUserInfo classes.
2. Breaking Change: Sign-in methods now return AuthResult instead of FirebaseUser. Retrieve the FirebaseUser using the user property of AuthResult.
   [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As its is mentioned here : https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth#0120
>
> 1. Added new AuthResult and AdditionalUserInfo classes.
> 2. Breaking Change: Sign-in methods now return AuthResult instead of FirebaseUser. Retrieve the FirebaseUser using the user property of AuthResult.

One should not get panicked. As a beginner, I was also confused and this will help the other beginners too.
We have to just do this:

[image]